# "Attempt to apply non-function" error when trying to write.csv

Tags: r

I'm just trying to export my data using `write.csv` like you'd expect

```
write.csv(df, "df.csv")
```

and I'm getting this error:

```
"Error in app$vspace(new_style$`margin-top` %||% 0) : attempt to apply non-function."
```

I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this/solve the issue! I double checked that my data is a standard class (it's a data.frame), but beyond that I'm at a loss because it looks like every other data.frame I've ever (successfully) exported. I'm not an experienced error-reader, but if it's helpful, the top line of the traceback is this:

```
clii__container_start(app, "span", class = funname)
```

I also did all the basics like quitting and restarting my R session, moving my working directory around, and checking if other data.frames can export -- they can, it's just this one that's stuck.

Here's the output for sessionInfo():

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 22000)
Matrix products: default
locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    
attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] fansi_0.4.2      assertthat_0.2.1 utf8_1.2.1       crayon_1.5.1     dplyr_1.0.8      R6_2.5.1        
 [7] DBI_1.1.2        lifecycle_1.0.1  magrittr_2.0.1   pillar_1.7.0     rlang_1.0.2      cli_3.2.0       
[13] rstudioapi_0.13  remotes_2.4.2    vctrs_0.3.8      generics_0.1.2   ellipsis_0.3.2   tools_4.1.0     
[19] glue_1.4.2       purrr_0.3.4      xfun_0.30        compiler_4.1.0   pkgconfig_2.0.3  knitr_1.39      
[25] tidyselect_1.1.2 tibble_3.1.2
```

and for rstudioapi::getVersion()

```
> rstudioapi::getVersion()
[1] ‘1.4.1106’
```

Comment: Are you sure your actual data.frame is named `df`? Can you please share the output of `sessionInfo()` and `rstudioapi::getVersion()`

Comment: @MrFlick Yes to the data.frame naming question, and I added the other info to the end of my original post. Thanks!

Comment: These error message seem to have to do with the formatting of error message, and not the actual `write.csv` command itself. It's not clear why this is happening. Have you been calling functions from libraries using `::` rather than `library()`? Otherwise I'm not sure why there are so many packages loaded via namespace rather than attached. The "bad" code is coming from the `cli` package but it's unclear what's triggering it. Are you sure the file isn't actually being created? Can you share a `dput()` of the data so we can test it?

Comment: @MrFlick I can definitely do that. A file is actually being created, but it only has the column names, no data. The `dput()` result is pretty large, though, because my data.frame is 3,226 x 324, so I'm not sure it'd be helpful to paste it all here. That being said -- part of the `dput()` output has data listed as 0L, 1L, 2L rather than 0, 1, 2 -- could that be the issue? The columns still say they're numeric, but it looks like they have a... length?